# Trending Words in Solr 4.0

Tags: solr, trending

Is anyone aware of any upcoming or plugin support for Solr 4.0 trending word/topic functionality?

I am aware of various DIY algorithmic approaches and some external frameworks that perhaps can be used (Mahout etc) but given its popularity i'd imagine there are already efforts to make this a part pluggable of Solr.

Failing that, if anyone can point to a resource that details using an external framework that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really hacky way to do it, you can capture incoming searches in your Solr front-end (PHP, or whatever) and then send them to an external database, and then query that database for top searches within a certain timeperiod, and outlier searches that are up-and-coming.